# Astra Mobile Cart Drawer is blank on home page

Tags: javascript

I am using woocommerce and astra theme with elementor. I have a cart icon in my header menu which opens the cart on desktop. On mobile, it slides out a cart drawer (provided by Astra I think). On the home page the slide out cart drawer shows a blank page instead of the cart info. On all other pages, the cart drawer shows as expected (with items in the cart). However, if the cart is empty, then the "cart empty" message that shows on desktop does not show on any of the mobile pages - it's just a blank page again.

I have disabled all plugin's except woocommerce and the astra theme, and the issue still persists. I changed to the Storefront theme and the icon then works as expected. So it's some setting in the Astra theme I assume. But for the life of me I cannot find the problem. I'm even happy to turn off the slide out drawer and just have the icon go to the cart page if that is possible?

The site is https://staging.resortstylebeanbags.com.au

Hoping someone can help provide some guidance

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Download and install Astra Child Theme if you haven't already.
2. Create a new file, name it as hide-mobile-cart-drawer.js and place
   it inside the Astra Child Theme folder.
3. Copy and paste the below code into the new file just created.

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
 
    var main_header_masthead = document.getElementById('masthead'),
        mobileHeader = main_header_masthead.querySelector("#ast-mobile-header");
 
    if (undefined !== mobileHeader && '' !== mobileHeader && null !== mobileHeader) {
 
        var woo_carts = document.querySelectorAll(".ast-mobile-header-wrap .ast-header-woo-cart");
 
        if( 0 < woo_carts.length ){
            woo_carts.forEach(function callbackFn(woo_cart) {
                if (undefined !== woo_cart && '' !== woo_cart && null !== woo_cart) {
                    woo_cart.removeEventListener("click", cartFlyoutOpen, false);
                }
            })
        }
    }
});
```

4. Add the code below to the functions.php file of the child theme.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'hide_mobile_cart_drawer' );
function hide_mobile_cart_drawer() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'hide-mobile-cart-drawer',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/hide-mobile-cart-drawer.js',
        array(),
        '',
        true
    );
}
```

Source:
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/mobile-cart-drawer/#post-15153919

Comment: Thanks. I found this and implemented it, but it's a workaround, not a fix. So the original issue still exists. But will mark this as accepted answer in lieu of no other solutions